# Unable to load one or more of the requested types - but not the normal error

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, autofac

Okay, so this is a really bizarre one that has been bugging me. It will be hard to explain so please bear with me!

I am using autofac to register some components by scanning references.

```
public static void RegisterHandlersKeyedByEnum(this ContainerBuilder builder, Assembly[] assembliesToScan, Type typeToRegister)
{
    var handlers = assembliesToScan.SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes()).Where(t => t.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeToRegister));

    foreach (var handler in handlers)
    {
        var handlesAttributes = handler.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(HandlesEnumOf), true).Cast<HandlesEnumOf>();
        foreach (var handlesAttribute in handlesAttributes)
        {
            if (handlesAttribute != null)
            {
                builder.RegisterType(handler).AsImplementedInterfaces().Keyed(handlesAttribute.Value, typeToRegister);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With assemblesToScanBeing:

```
var assembliesToScan = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
```

When I run the web app, I get the following error:

> Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.

I know what the error is, and have fixed it many times. However if I just refresh the page after ~10-15 seconds, the error no longer appears and the web app is okay to use from then on.

When I looked into this further and inspected LoaderExceptions, the following type was failing to load "Viper.ViewModels.Users.ADUserViewModel". This is where it get's weird. That file does NOT exist, anywhere. Not by searching for files, not even by searching for text. I found out it was a class that was created on a completely separate branch that was never actually merged into master (using GIT).

Now to make it even more weird, if I add in the class ADUserViewModel to Viper.ViewModels/Users folder and even leave the class completely empty. The project runs without any issues/errors whatsoever.

I mean, I could leave the empty class there, it's not doing any harm. But it will really bug me that A) It's unnecessary and B) I don't actually know why this is happening.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated and put my mind at rest! I'm not sure what code can be posted to help explain this better, but more than happy to provide some if needed.

Comment: There's not enough info to really help you - you should include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help people understand. For example, there's not enough information here to determine what is trying to load the model type in question or why, so you'll likely not get a sufficient answer. Seeing registration code and the full stack trace may help.

Comment: @TravisIllig I have added the registration code where it causes the error.

Comment: As you update your question, try to step outside yourself and think about it like you don't know literally anything about your app.  What kind of app is it? What calls this registration code that causes the error? Did the exception include info on what was trying to load the missing type? Are all of the app assemblies being scanned part of the same solution? Anything cached out built on the fly? Try reading your question back and imagining you've never heard of your app. Is there enough to let someone try to recreate the issue or see the problem in action?